# Interactive Machine Learning App to make Predictions using Descriptors

Tags: manipulate, machine-learning, chemistry

I have developed a Machine Learning algorithm that uses 4 chemical descriptors to calculate a chosen chemical property. I would like to create an interactive app on Mathematica (using the manipulate function) to make predictions of the chosen property by inserting values of the 4 descriptors. Currently, I am able to perform this on my notebook using the following code:

```
pred2o = Predict[trainingSet1, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"]
pred2o[{20, 146, 2.5, 0.55}]
73.3435
pred2o[{100, 100, 100, 0}]
672.989
```

I would like to be able to convert this same idea into an app that can be accessed outside of this notebook where you can insert chosen values for each of these descriptors and automatically retrieve the predicted value using the developed machine learning algorithm. If possible, I was thinking of having a text box for each descriptor where you can type a numerical value for each, and once you do that the predicted value is shown. For context, the descriptors are Atom Count, Molecular Mass, Radius of Gyration, and Plane of Best Fit Distance, respectively. The output value is Molecular Surface Area. My plan is to have each text box labeled accordingly so that it clear what each text box represents.

I have looked through the Manipulate documentation and have not viewed it being applied to Machine Learning, so if anyone can provide me with the code to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please post `trainingSet1`

Comment: @ConorCosnett added! If you would like any more information, please let me know. The full code is quite long and may have code that is not directly related to this inquiry. However, it may help if you had access to it so you can assist with this task. Please let me know if you would need that and I can send you it through a less public means. Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted does not work as `bioData` is undefined. `trainingSet1` is a function of `bioData`. So I still do not have access to `trainingSet1`.

Comment: @ConorCosnett Oh, I see. The bioData also includes variables that would be undefined so the best option would be to send you the entire notebook. If you can provide me a way to send you the notebook link privately, let me know (if there is a way to private message through this platform that would be great).

Comment: There is no private messenger service that I know of. Maybe you could copy and paste a sample of `trainingSet1`?

Comment: Maybe you could make up a simpler problem with 2 descriptors. There are lots of examples of data sets in the documentation.

Comment: @ConorCosnett I attached the bioData portion to the message. I hope that this can help.

Comment: My network is too slow to download all the data from Wolfram's server. It would really help if you could run `RandomSample[trainingSet1, 100]` and copy and paste the output into your question.

Comment: @ConorCosnett No problem at all! I just added that to the question. Please let me know if there is anything else I should add. Thanks.

Comment: @ConorCosnett Thank you for the help. I viewed your answer and that was exactly what I was looking for! By any chance are you aware of how I can make this accessible to public use. I attempted to use the CloudDeploy function but it did not work. I assume this is because there is an undefined variable in the manipulate function. If you have an alternative, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @ConorCosnett Sorry to interrupt you again. I just wanted to check in if you can assist and clarity with my previous inquiry to make this code accessible for use on Wolfram Cloud. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

## idea 1

```
Manipulate[
 pred2o[{atomCount, molecularMass, radiusOfGyration, 
   planeOfBestFitDistance} ], {atomCount, 20}, {molecularMass, 
  146}, {radiusOfGyration, 2.5}, {planeOfBestFitDistance, 0.55}, 
 ControlType -> InputField]
```

[image]

## idea 2

```
Manipulate[
 
 pred2o[
  {atomCount, molecularMass, radiusOfGyration, planeOfBestFitDistance}]
 
 , {{atomCount, 20}, 2, 120, 1}
 , {{molecularMass, 146}, 26.038`, 822.942`}
 , {{radiusOfGyration, 2.5}, 0.22462`, 10.7024`}
 , {{planeOfBestFitDistance, 0.55}, 0.`, 1.22643`}]
```

[image]

## Adding a label to denote the output

```
Manipulate[
 
 "Molecular Surface Area = " <> ToString[pred2o[
    {atomCount, molecularMass, radiusOfGyration, 
     planeOfBestFitDistance}] ]
 
 , {{atomCount, 20}, 2, 120, 1}
 , {{molecularMass, 146}, 26.038`, 822.942`}
 , {{radiusOfGyration, 2.5}, 0.22462`, 10.7024`}
 , {{planeOfBestFitDistance, 0.55}, 0.`, 1.22643`}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate that you provided multiple options for me to choose from. Is it possible to make this app available for use to people who do not have Mathematica? Is there is a way to export the app in this interactive form for public use? Thank you again!